# Conditional statements in Clojurescript with Hoplon and cells not working

Tags: clojurescript, boot-clj, hoplon

I have a question regarding conditionals and Hoplon. When I try:

```
(defn mouse-enter
  [temp stuff]
  (reset! temp @stuff)
  (if (= "y" "y")
      (reset! mon-width {:width "0%"})))
```

It changes the CSS width property to 0, but, if I try using a cell in any way it doesn't seem to work. IE.

```
(def week-view (cell "y"))
(def mon-width (cell {:width "50.333%"}))

(defn mouse-enter
  [temp stuff]
  (reset! temp @stuff)
  (if (= "y" (cell= week-view))
      (reset! mon-width {:width "0%"})))
```

Or:

```
(defn mouse-enter
  [temp stuff]
  (reset! temp @stuff)
  (if (= "y" (str (cell= week-view)))
      (reset! mon-width {:width "0%"})))
```

Or:

```
 (defn mouse-enter
   [temp stuff]
   (reset! temp @stuff)
   (when (= "y" (str (cell= week-view)))
         (reset! mon-width {:width "0%"})))
```

Or:

```
 (defn mouse-enter
   [temp stuff]
   (reset! temp @stuff)
   (when (= (cell= "y") (cell= week-view))
         (reset! mon-width {:width "0%"})))
```

And this one works even though the value of week-view has changed.

```
(def week-view (cell "n"))
(def mon-width (cell {:width "50.333%"}))

(defn mouse-enter
  [temp stuff]
  (reset! temp @stuff)
  (when (= (str (cell= "y")) (str (cell= week-view)))
        (reset! mon-width {:width "0%"})))
```

I don't really know what is going on but I am just trying to get the true conditional active when 'week-view' is set to "y". I tried booleans, that didn't seem to work and a lot of other stuff.

Cheers,
Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured it out. You can use the @ symbol to get the value of the cell. Here is the new code that works.

```
(def week-view (cell nil))
(def mon-width (cell {:width "8.333%"}))

(defn mouse-enter
  [temp stuff]
  (reset! temp @stuff)
  (when (= nil @week-view)
        (reset! mon-width {:width "30%"})))
```

Cheers,
Matt

Comment: You may also consider wrapping both `reset!` calls in a `dosync`. That causes the resets to happen together as a single "transaction". It doesn't necessarily fix any bugs now but will make your code easier to think about later.